# Passing PHP into jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an idea how to pass PHP value into a jQuery variable, I have done it in the past and it worked. But I tried the below code but for some reason it not working. I dont know where the problem lies.

I am trying to hide a custom virtuemart drop down cart I designed when the cart is empty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   
var cart = "<?php if ($data->totalProduct) echo  $data->cart_show; ?>"
jQuery('.btn-cart1').hover(if (cart === "") {
jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').hide();
} 
else {          
jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').hide();
jQuery('.btn-cart1').hover(
    function() { jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').stop().show(500)},
    function() { jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').stop().hide(500)})
}
});
```

Comment: Explain _not working_ What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: open console read error and post here

Comment: The error is <?php echo $catURL ?>:455 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side scripting language and is executed well before your javascript executes on web browser.

The correct execution of your code depends on the values of `$data->totalProduct & $data->cart_show` after the PHP has been executed on your server side and the values are places in your javascript.

It is not a good programming practice and I would strongly suggest you to use AJAX instead to access the values of PHP variables.